# MPAndroidChart white Background

Tags: android, background, mpandroidchart

I am using the [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library. I am setting the multi line chart with data using MPAndroidChart. It's working great but the background is coming white. This is what i am doing

```
        nhChart = new LineChart(getActivity());
        nhChart.setDescription("Number of Hits View");
        nhChart = (LineChart) hitsView.findViewById(R.id.line_chart_number_of_hits);

        //int color = Color.parseColor("#80101010");
        nhChart.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80101010"));
        //nhChart.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.background_portrate);
        //nhChart.setBackground(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.background_portrate));

        nhChart.setStartAtZero(true);   
        nhChart.setDrawBorder(true);

        nhChart.setNoDataTextDescription("No Data available for Charts");

        nhChart.setDrawYValues(false);
        nhChart.setDrawBorder(true);
        nhChart.setScaleEnabled(true);

        nhChart.setHighlightEnabled(false);
        nhChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
        //nhChart.setGridColor(Color.WHITE & 0x70FFFFFF);
        //nhChart.setDragScaleEnabled(true);    
        nhChart.setPinchZoom(true);

        setData(valueDate.size(),10000);
        nhChart.animateX(2500);

        Legend l = nhChart.getLegend();
        l.setForm(LegendForm.CIRCLE);
        l.setFormSize(6f);
        l.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

        YLabels y = nhChart.getYLabels();
        y.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        y.setLabelCount(6);

        XLabels x1 = nhChart.getXLabels();
        x1.setCenterXLabelText(true);
        x1.setPosition(XLabelPosition.BOTTOM);
        x1.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

I am plotting line graphs in post execute method of AsyncTask in a fragment viewpager. Other fragment showing the graph shows the same white background. I tried setting a color for the background but nothing works. I also left it blank, but its still showing me the white background. I also updated the latest Jar but its not works. Please help.
Here is the image how it looks

Answer (score 5):

You want this for transparent:

```
chart.setDrawGridBackground(false);
```

And this for transparent bar:

```
chart.setDrawBarShadow(false);
```

Comment: how to add x-axis description (at Bottom) and y-axis description at left ? could you help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

Well by default, the backgroud of the chart is **transparent** which means that it will have whatever color you set for the view/layout below the chart.

If you want to change the background (color, or maybe drawable), you can do that in the following ways:

- in .xml (`android:background="..."`)
  --> set the background color of the chart in xml or set the backgroud color of the layout the chart is in.
- by calling `setBackgroundColor(...)` or `setBackgroundResource(...)`

I guess you want your background to be some kind of black?
What happens if you call:

`chart.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK)`?

Does setting the background-color work then? Also check the example code in the github repo [**here**](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/tree/master/MPChartExample). There are some cases in the example app that change the background color.

Comment: Hi Philipp, thanks for reply. I had tried everything you mention and tried to implement as it was mention in the repo but i am still getting a white background.It is a bit weird, but i am getting desire background with bar chart and radar chart, but with line chart its showing only white background with gradient. I could have posted the image, but since my reputation is low i can't do that.

Comment: Does not work for me. What ever I try I get the chart to be of some dull grey colour. It is definitely not transparent.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with:

```
chart.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.transparent));
```

Please define first:

```
<color name="transparent">#00000000</color>
```